# matrix diagonalization and basis change with geev

Tags: fortran, lapack

I want to diagonalize a matrix and then be able to do basis changes. The aim in the end is to do matrix exponentiation, with `exp(A) = P.exp(D).P^{-1}`.

I use `sgeev` to diagonalize `A`. If I am not mistaken (and I probably am since it's not working), `sgeev` gives me `P` in the `vr` matrix and `P^{-1}` is `transpose(vl)`. The diagonal matrix can be reconstitute from the eigenvalues `wr`.

The problem is that when I try to verify the matrix transformation by computing `P * D * P^{-1}` it's not giving A back.

Here's my code:

```
integer :: i,n, info
real::norm
real, allocatable:: A(:,:), B(:,:), C(:,:),D(:,:)
real, allocatable:: wr(:), wi(:), vl(:, :), vr(:, :), work(:)

n=3
allocate(vr(n,n), vl(n,n), wr(n), wi(n), work(4*n))
allocate(A(n,n),B(n,n), C(n,n),D(n,n))

A(1,:)=(/1,0,1/)
A(2,:)=(/0,2,1/)
A(3,:)=(/0,3,1/)

call sgeev('V','V',n,A,n,wr,wi,vl,n,vr,n,work,size(work,1),info)
print*,'eigenvalues'
do i=1,n
  print*,i,wr(i),wi(i)
enddo

D=0.0
D(1,1)=wr(1)
D(2,2)=wr(2)
D(3,3)=wr(3)

C = matmul(D,transpose(vl))
B = matmul(vr,C)

print*,'A'
do i=1, n
  print*, B(i,:)
enddo
```

The printed result is:

```
                    eigenvalues
                    1   1.00000000       0.00000000    
                    2   3.30277562       0.00000000    
                    3 -0.302775621       0.00000000  
 A
  0.688247263      0.160159975      0.764021933    
   0.00000000       1.66581571      0.817408621    
   0.00000000       2.45222616      0.848407149
```

A is not the original A, not even considering an eventual factor.
I guess I am somehow mistaken since I checked the eigenvectors by computing `matmul(A,vr) = matmul(vr,D)` and `matmul(transpose(vl),A) = matmul(D, transpose(vl))`, and it worked.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `transpose(vl)` is not the inverse of `vr`. The normalisation given by [`sgeev`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/dfb/group__real_g_eeigen_ga104525b749278774f7b7f57195aa6798.html) is that each eigenvector (each column of `vl` or `vr`) is individually normalised. This means that `dot_product(vl(:,i), vr(:,j))` is zero if `i/=j`, but is in general `<1` if `i==j`.

If you want to get `P^{-1}`, you need to scale each column of `vl` by a factor of `1/dot_product(vl(:,i),vr(:,i)` before transposing it.